# How to change RowMatrix into Array in Spark or export it as a CSV?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I've got this code in Scala:

```
val mat: CoordinateMatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(data)
val rowMatrix: RowMatrix = mat.toRowMatrix()

val svd: SingularValueDecomposition[RowMatrix, Matrix] = rowMatrix.computeSVD(100, computeU = true)

val U: RowMatrix = svd.U // The U factor is a RowMatrix.
val S: Vector = svd.s // The singular values are stored in a local dense vector.
val V: Matrix = svd.V // The V factor is a local dense matrix.

val uArray: Array[Double] = U.toArray // doesn't work, because there is not toArray function in RowMatrix type
val sArray: Array[Double] = S.toArray // works good
val vArray: Array[Double] = V.toArray // works good
```

How can I change *U* into *uArray* or similar type, that could be printed out into CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a basic operation, here is what you have to do considering that U is a RowMatrix as following :

```
val U = svd.U
```

> rows() is a RowMatrix method that allows you to get an RDD from your RowMatrix by row.

You'll just need to apply  rows on your RowMatrix and map the RDD[Vector] to create an Array that you would concatenate into a string creating an RDD[String].

```
val rdd = U.rows.map( x => x.toArray.mkString(","))
```

All you'll have to do now it to save the RDD :

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile(path)
```

Comment: Don't know why, but saveAsTexFile didn't work as I expected. However, using your tip and rows() function, I finally exported it. Thank you :)

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: I thought that I will receive a .txt, .csv or similar file, which I could view in Excel. But it was creating a folder with the name of last string from file path and then it throw a NullPointerException. I made a "quick fix", I will post it in answer.

Comment: well yes, saveAsTextFile writes partitions so you can't get a txt file or a csv file. what I usually do is `cat`command over the files in the folder to a csv file, like `cat test/part-* > test.csv`

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
def exportRowMatrix(matrix:RDD[String], fileName: String) = {
  val pw = new PrintWriter(fileName)
  matrix.collect().foreach(line => pw.println(line))

  pw.flush
  pw.close
}

val rdd = U.rows.map( x => x.toArray.mkString(","))
exportRowMatrix(rdd, "U.csv")
```

Comment: the only issue with the collect method is that if the matrix is too big, it will give you a Java Heap Error, so be careful with that!

Comment: @eliasah Wow! I've already had a Java Heap Error, so now I know why. I increased memory in Spark settings and the problem was gone ;)

Comment: Increasing the memory is not always a good solution, but if it works for you then it's good